# Why Sequential Feature Selector doesn't remove features with STD=0

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, mlxtend

I'm running feature selection with `mlxtend` library:

```
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(classifier,
           k_features="best", 
           forward=True, 
           floating=True, 
           scoring='average_precision',
           cv=2,
           n_jobs=-1)
```

But it seems that is preserved features with standard deviation = 0

How can it be ?

I read that wrapper methods suppose to give best results, and it seems that features with STD=0 need to be the first features to exclude.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Why are you certain that Forward Floating Feature Selection removes features with a standard deviation of 0? Nowhere in the `mlextend` package does it say that.

Comment: I saw that after using the feature selection, there are some feature with std=0. Features with std=0 doesn't increase the scoring function (and not decrease it), so I wonder if I need to remove them before calling SequentialFeatureSelector